# Catching non-ascii KeyEvent using toggleSoftInput and dispatchKeyEvent

Tags: java, android, android-activity, keyevent

I am trying to catch non-ascii characters from the soft keyboard (without using an EditText).

To toggle soft keyboard I use:

```
     InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)editScreen.getActivity()
            .getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Then from the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    char keyChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    char keyLabel = event.getDisplayLabel();
    ...
    return false;
}
```

This is working with ASCII characters, but not with non-ascii characters (German, Hebrew).
Seems like the events are not even being registered.
How to get it to work with non-ascii?
Thanks in advance